# Passing information to modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using angularjs and bootstrap to create a modal. The modal is going to display an image. I get the image source through the database using an email address associated with the image. However I am not sure how to pass the information to the modal to get the image itself.

html

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in timeSheets">
    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.period}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.status}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.regHours}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.overHours}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.totHours}}</td>
    <td><div ng-controller=imageController>
        <a ng-click="imageModal(employee.username)">Attachment</a>
    </div></td>
```

imageControllerJS-

```
function imageController ($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.imageModal = function() {
        alert("inside ImageModal");
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl : 'HTML/imageModal.html',

            controller : imageModalController,

        });
    };  
}
```

imageModal-js

```
function imageModalController($scope, $http, employeeFactory,$routeParams,modalInstance) {
    $scope.params = $routeParams.username;
    $scope.getImageReturn = function(data) {
        $scope.img_source = data.path;
        alert($scope.img_source);
        //data.path;
    };
    $scope.getImage = function(email) {

        employeeFactory.getImage(email);

    };
    $scope.getImage($scope.params);
    $scope.cancel = function() {

        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
```

UPDATED CODE FROM ANSWER BELOW

```
    function imageController ($scope, $modal) {
$scope.imageModal = function() {
    alert("inside loginModal");
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl : 'HTML/imageModal.html',
        controller : imageModalController,
        resolve: { imageInfo: function() {return username; }}
    });
};
```

}

```
    imageModalController.$inject = ['imageInfo']
    function imageModalController($scope, $http, employeeFactory,$routeParams,modalInstance) {
$scope.imageInfo = imageInfo;
alert("imageinfo");
$scope.getImageReturn = function(data) {
    $scope.img_source = data.path;
    alert($scope.img_source);
    //data.path;
};




    Now spitting out
    ReferenceError: imageInfo is not defined
at new imageModalController (http://localhost/Employee_12_30_AngularJS/JS/imageModal.js:4:21)
at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js:30:346)
at Object.instantiate (
```

Comment: you could pass a resolve to your $modal.open similar to passing it to your routes

Comment: could you give me an example so i can see how its done? sorry kinda new to this

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in your image ctrl just pass in a resolve with the data you need.

```
function imageController ($scope, $modal) {
  $scope.imageModal = function() {
    alert("inside ImageModal");
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl : 'HTML/imageModal.html',

      controller : imageModalController,
      resolve: { imageInfo: function() {return thingYouSendToModal; }
   });
 };  
}
```

Then just inject imageInfo inside of your modal ctrl and set $scope.imageInfo = imageInfo to initialize it.

Comment: I updated it with your code but now am getting errors, Check up top for updated code

Comment: You need to inject imageInfo into your modal controller, it should be in this line function imageModalController($scope, $http, employeeFactory,$routeParams,modalInstance, IMAGE INFO HERE)

Answer (score 0):

imageControllerJS-

```
function imageController ($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.imageModal = function(email) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl : 'HTML/imageModal.html',

            controller : imageModalController,
            resolve: {
                   resolved_email: function(){
                        return email;
                  }
             }

        });
    };  
}
```

imageModal-js

```
function imageModalController($scope, $http, employeeFactory,$routeParams,modalInstance,resolved_email) {
    $scope.params = $routeParams.username;
    $scope.getImageReturn = function(data) {
        $scope.img_source = data.path;
        alert($scope.img_source);
        //data.path;
    };
    $scope.getImage = function() {

        employeeFactory.getImage(resolved_email);

    };
    $scope.getImage($scope.params);
    $scope.cancel = function() {

        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
```